# Move Envelope to Recycle Bin

Tags: docusignapi

Using the DocuSign V2 REST API, I am trying to call the [Move Envelope](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm?utm_campaign=DevCenter%20Nurture%20Campaign%20Email%201%20-%20Key%20Information&utm_medium=email&utm_source=Eloqua#REST%20API%20References/Move%20Envelope.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____98) method to put an envelope in the recycle bin.

Here is what my request looks like:

> [PUT]
>
> https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/folders/recyclebin

And here's what my request body looks like:

```
{"envelopeIds":["05912aa6-fb05-4168-a499-999b20ec1ca6"]}
```

But for any `envelopeId` I send, I get the following error:

> ENVELOPE_NOT_IN_FOLDER - The envelope does not exist in the folder

I'm not sure what this means because the envelope does exist, so I'm not sure why it can't be found. I've tried with completed envelopes as well as envelopes which have been created but aren't yet signed.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or have any other details on what this error message means? I can't find much online about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sending the designated sender in the `<DocuSignCredentials>` authentication header to specify the sender who originally sent the envelope. Once I added this, everything was working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your Request URL is missing `envelopes/`

This should work for you:

`https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/folders/recyclebin`

Comment: Interesting... That's not what their documentation says. I'll give that a try. Thanks!!

Comment: I see conflicting information between 3 different documents. I'm running some testing now to see the results.

Comment: Both ways work for me, let me know your results on the second way. What is the current status of that envelope/

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error, this envelope has a status of "completed."

Comment: did you specify `fromFolderId` or leave it? In my case, I won't know (or care, really) what folder the evnelope is currently in. I just want to move completed envelopes to the recycle bin.

Comment: Ugh - nevermind. Apparently you have to specify the designated sender if the envelope had originally been sent on behalf of someone. The original URL worked from the documentation I found, but apparently when authenticating as the parent admin account, the envelope in question could not be found. It is working correctly now.